# AndEngine Image on part of a sprite

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm working on a game which integrates Facebook. In a certain scene, the user can choose an opponent from the list of Facebook friends who have installed the game.

I want to create this menu of friends, I know how to create the list, I know how to get the friends who have the app installed, and how to get their info. What I don't know, is how to create a sprite, which would have, for example, the user's profile image on the left, his name   and score on the right, and to have this whole thing act as a sprite (or a `SpriteButton`)

Can anyone point me to the right direction?
Since I obtain the info from Facebook, I can't, obviously, have the Sprites pre-made.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use AndEngine entities for this, as there is nothing ready to suit your needs (You'll have to make this on your own).

Instead, use the regular android dialogs. You can use your own layout which consists the profile picture and any other text you want.

Comment: I was thinking of making a dialog with a `ListView` in it, But I wanted to keep the overall "graphic" look of the game, not incorporating any native UI-Elements.. Do you think that's a valid and good way?

Comment: I guessed that would be the problem (Keeping the overall graphic look). It's true that keeping this look will make the game look better, but it will take a lot of time that should be used in making other parts of the game better (This is not crucial - many games use the native UI elements).

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I guess I'll do it this way then. Thanks.